# Query Access Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to query an access db using visual basic but I'm looking for a little explanation on how this actually works.

What I'm confused about is that I state a command `SELECT * FROM PI` (`PI` Being the table) but then directly below that, I'm saying that `TextBox1.Text = theDataTable.Rows(0).Item(1)`.

I'm just wondering why I have a query command and then a seperate command that is going to a specified Row and Item....any help is much appreciated!

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Dim theConnectionString As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    txtSQL.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    theConnectionString.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Marc Wilson\Documents\FiddleFuckDB.accdb"
    theConnectionString.Open()
    Dim theDataSet As New DataSet
    Dim theDataTable As New DataTable
    theDataSet.Tables.Add(theDataTable)
    Dim theDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter

    theDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PI", theConnectionString)
    theDataAdapter.Fill(theDataTable)

    TextBox1.Text = theDataTable.Rows(0).Item(1)



    theConnectionString.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
"SELECT * FROM PI Where FieldName = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
```

assumed that your field type is not numeric

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an ADO.NET DataTable - that object consist of Rows collection and each row in turn consists of Items collection. So in order to get to a specific value you need to use

```
Table.Rows(X)(Y)
```

notation. Even if your query returns a single value - you would use this approach. Looking at your code and `Items(1)` especially, it looks like your query returns at least 2 columns.

If you're interested in a single value only, consider specifying a single column name in your query, make sure that it returns a single row (e.g. by adding `WHERE` clause to your query) and use `ExecuteScalar` ADO.NET command, which, unlike Fill and DataTable returns a single value only.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I undertand the question, but hopefully this helps:

The query command is fetching all of the records from the table in your database. The Rows() and Item() methods fetch a particular field from a particular record (in this case, the second field of the first record).

The Text property of your TextBox cannot display the entire table on it's own: the DataTable is a fairly complicated data strucutre. TextBoxes require a string (or something like one).

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM PI` tells the database engine which data it should retrieve from the underlying database table that exists *on-disk*.

You're using the `DataTable` class which represents data *in-memory*: the `DataAdapter` class reads data from disk (using the SQL statement) and copies it into memory, where you then use the  `Rows(0).Item(1)` command to get a copy of the data already in memory.

The alternative is to use `DataReader` which is more direct, often simpler. In your case I don't see why you're using the `DataTable` class because `DataReader` will suit you fine.